# See declaration of method in html file (Concordion)

Tags: java, concordion

do any of you have any idea how to see the declaration of a method used in a corncordion HtML file, other way then searching the whole project ?

ex :

```
   <th concordion:assertEquals="#Object.field">Expected Name</th>
   <th concordion : assertEquals= "#Object.method">Expected</th>
```

P.S : I've also tried the concordion support plugin but it was not helpful.
P.S2 : I'm using IntelliJ IDEA

Answer (score 0):

The [Concordion support](https://github.com/concordion/idea-concordion-support) plugin you mentioned in your Post Script should satisfy your requirements.

I am currently using Idea community edition 2016.3.5 with Concordion Support plugin 0.11.1

Navigating between code / spec / definition

Given the example snippet below

```
 <!-- searchString and ignoreCase are defined elsewhere in document -->
 <table concordion:verifyRows="#field: helper().withNames(#searchString,#ignoreCase)">

 <!-- clicking on #field below navigates to the above definition -->
 <th concordion:assertEquals="#field">Expected Name</th>
```

- clicking on **helper** navigates to my helper property in my backing class
- clicking on **withNames** navigates to withNames method of my helper instance
- clicking on **field** / **searchString** / **ignoreCase** navigates to respected declarations

If I recall, it didn't initially work without the correct project structure (File -> Project Structure) settings.

i.e.

- my specs (html / md files) must be set to 'test resources'
- backing fixtures (.java / .scala etc) must be set to 'test sources'

At which point, icons also appeared on the left of the code editor to also navigate between spec and fixture.

The HTML extension navigation seems to work pretty well with the possible exception of more complex expressions requiring the [@FullOGNL](http://concordion.org/coding/java/html/#full-ognl) annotation and some possible short-form notations.

I've had success using HTML + Java 8 / Scala, Markdown + Java 8 / Scala

If you are able to provide a specific testable snippet (i.e. Github + Maven / Gradle simple project) with code that compiles / executes properly but IDE navigation fails, someone may be able to provide a better or more helpful answer than I have provided.